# kasm docker runconfig override json with network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I want to set **hostname**, **networkname** and **ip** in ***kasm*** `Docker Run Config Override (JSON)`. so far I've tried this json and many others but the app simply won't start.
I want to know where can i find the full log of exception and if I am sending wrong json keys please let me know :

```
{
"hostname":"customName",
"network":"customNetwork",
"ipv4_address": "172.23.111.28"
}
```